# Is duplicate syntax for defining named functions a bad language design decision?

Tags: language-design, scala

I am modelling a programming language for fun, and the syntax is heavily influenced by Scala - specifically function definitions.

I have encountered a design problem because my language **does not differentiate** between functions defined via the `def` syntax (class methods) and anonymous functions assigned to values (created using `=>`) - it removes the differences in both [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530007/924313) and [behaviour](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html).

The result is that the following two definitions mean the same thing:

```
def square(x: Int) = x*x

val square = (x: Int) => x*x
```

There is no reason for the latter form (immediate anonymous function assignment) to be used in any normal situation - it's simply *possible* to use it instead of the `def` form.

**Would having such duplicate syntax for defining named functions hurt the orthogonality of the language or some other design aspect?**

I prefer this solution because it allows for short and intuitive definitions of methods and named functions (via `def`), and short definitions of anonymous functions (using `=>`).

Edit: **Scala *does* differentiate between the two** - anonymous functions are not the same as methods defined with `def` in Scala. The differences are relatively subtle though - see the posts I linked before.

Comment: `However, assigning existing functions` seems to be missing the end of the sentence

Comment: Can you define recursive functions using your `val` notation?

Comment: @Giorgio Good question, the answer is yes, it is possible because of [forward referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22108579/924313).

Comment: I verified that this is possible in Scala too. In SML it is not and you have to use `fun` to define a recursive function.

Comment: The second form isn't really a special syntactical structure, the way `def` is. It's just a side effect of the fact that an anonymous function, say `(x : Int) => x + 1` is an object, and objects can be assigned to values with `val f = ...`. The language designers would have had to _go out of their way_ to disallow the syntax. It's not quite the same as explicitly putting in the effort to support two different syntaxes that do (approximately) the same thing.

Comment: @Giorgio In SML it can be done using `val rec`. `fun` is a syntactic sugar for `val rec` plus currying.

Comment: Is it fair to refer to Javascript? Javascript works that way... `var f0 = function() {...}` ... `function f1() {...}` `f0() === f1()` ...as a practical perspective.

Comment: The major benefit of doing something more than one way in a language is it is a great way to start unproductive religious debates which distract from the real problems (Thinking C++ here) .......

Comment: @Doval: Exactly: you have to use `val rec` so that the name you are defining is in scope in the right-hand side. If you use `val` alone, the right-hand side of the definition does not know the name that is being defined.

Comment: I'd say that the `def` form is extraneous, because `val` works for everything and `def` special-cases functions. Note that anonymous functions work _slightly_ differently, according to @jco's answer below. (And no, I don't like this kind of design, in languages or otherwise.)

Comment: @9000 in Scala the difference is significant though. Lambdas return from enclosing methods (def), they cannot have type parameters, and to get the same forward referencing behaviour, you'd have to define them as `lazy val`s. Why don't you like this kind of design though? What alternative would you prefer?

Comment: @jco: I would prefer that there was ["one — and preferably only one — obvious way to do it"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), and the idea of returning from an enclosing scope looks dubious to me w.r.t. composability, but here I am firmly on the 'opinion-based' ground and thus should fall silent.

Answer (score 3):

I think that having two constructs that mean the same thing but look different should be kept to an absolutely minimum in a language. Any duplication increases how difficult it is to read (and thus write/modify code in ) your language. Eliminating *all* duplication is unavoidable in a language that can create arbitrary constructs (for example, the equivalence of iteration vs recursion).

So in this case, I think it could be designed better here. A single way to define functions makes the most sense to me. In this case, it sounds like the two scala statements you have actually do have slightly different implications, which again is probably not good design (probably best to have something clear that states what the differences, like a keyword).

In fact, you can apply this principle not only to named functions, but to *any* function. Why have any difference in defining named functions and anonymous functions? In [Lima](http://www.btetrud.com/Lima/Lima-Documentation.html), functions are always defined like this: `fn[<arguments>: <statements>]`. If you want it to be "named" you can assign it to a variable: `var x = fn[<arguments: <statements>]`, and if you want to pass it in to another function anonymously: `function[fn[<arguments: <statements>]]`. If you want it hoisted, make it constant `const var x = fn[<arguments: <statements>]`. The single form makes it obvious that they mean the same thing.

Comment: That's quite interesting that `const` causes hoisting, but it makes perfect sense. In JS `function myFunc` causes hoisting, but `var myFunc =` does not, which is perhaps a bit less intuitive because they behave pretty much the same otherwise.

Comment: @mpen Yeah, actually javascript essentially does the same thing. the `function fnName()...` form does in fact create a constant, which is what makes hoisting a valid thing to do with it. Javascript makes things pretty confusing tho when you use the form `var fn = function anotherFnName()...` since that makes the name `anotherFnName` *not* hoist, even tho its clearly constant.

Answer (score 2):

What you've posted is valid scala and works fine.

Given that the doubling hasn't caused issues with scala (to my knowledge), I'm going to say that it won't be a problem for your language either.

Comment: It is valid in Scala, it mostly works the same, but it does not mean the same thing - and if you'd make more complex examples (type polymorphism is not available for anonymous functions e.g.) - the differences would become more apparent.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a fundamental difference between lambdas and `def` methods in Scala - that I am still not sure whether I want to implement. I have to do further research on it and then I'll report back on my decision.

Essentially, only methods can `return` - and when the keyword is used from a lambda, it actually returns from the encompassing method.

As I've said, I'm not sure whether I want this. But it could be justification enough for this syntax. Or maybe too dangerous because subtle differences can unexpectedly cause harm.

[Details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17754976/924313)